# Interpret output from bash in Python's subprocess module

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I have been going through the `subprocess` module examples on Doug Helmann's [PYMOPTW](https://pymotw.com/3/subprocess/index.html#capturing-output). Here's the code snippet that I have trouble with.

```
# subprocess_run_output_error.py
import subprocess

try:
    completed = subprocess.run(
        'echo to stdout; echo to stderr 1>&2; exit 1',
        check=True,
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    print('ERROR:', err)
else:
    print('returncode:', completed.returncode)
    print('Have {} bytes in stdout: {!r}'.format(
        len(completed.stdout),
        completed.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
    )
```

I understand that `exit 1` is supposed to throw an error and the except clause is run.

```
to stderr 
ERROR: Command 'echo to stdout; echo to stderr 1>&2; exit 1' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I don't get why `to stdout` is not printed but `to stderr`. Doesn't `1>&2` appear after `echo to stdout` has been run?

For better understanding, I changed the code to see if I could get the `else` portion to run so I switched it to `exit 0`. When I did so, the output that I got was:

```
to stderr
returncode: 0
Have 10 bytes in stdout: 'to stdout\n'
```

I don't seem to understand what the `1>2` means despite going to [cheatsheets](https://github.com/LeCoupa/awesome-cheatsheets/blob/master/languages/bash.sh).

1. Again `to stderr` was printed. Why isn't `to stdout` printed out first since it appeared first?
2. Why is the `CompletedProcess` object only holding on to `to stderr`
   and not `to stdout`?
3. If I understand the [cheatsheet's](https://github.com/LeCoupa/awesome-cheatsheets/blob/master/languages/bash.sh) portion below, why isn't `to stderr` sent to the standard error stream if it's file descriptor is `2`?

> n>&m   # file descriptor n is made to be a copy of the output file
>   descriptor

The other question that I found relatively close to this was [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635065/what-is-the-differences-between-and-21). However, it was comparing `&>` and `>&`. I couldn't make sense of the initial `>&` so I felt even more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because you captured it, sou you have it available at `completed.stdout`.
2. Because you only captured stdout: `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, but no `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`
3. It is actually sent to stderr, that's why it is printed at the beginning, because you didn't captured it and that stream is unbuffered.

Comment: So `echo to stderr 1>&2;` means pipe to stdout to stderr?

Comment: Yes. It means `1` (file descriptor 1) `>` (is redirected) `&2` (to file descriptor 2). And usually, 0==stdin, 1==stdout and 2==stderr.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757862/what-does-12-mean-in-bash